# Large strings (eg. image dataURL) are not completely passing from client to server by POST method in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, server, xmlhttprequest

I’m working on a chat application using **Node+JS** at localhost, and its structure is as follows,

```
- index.js (server-side)
- style.css
- script.js (client-side)
- chats.txt (file to store text)
- bin (folder to store images)
- index.html
```

I don't know where to upload these fullstack apps, so I've uploaded the whole project here: https://repl.it/@RahulVerma8/BlogApp.

The repl is not as useful as one may think, except for the code reference. I'll suggest to copy it locally and run it on localhost, to feel the project. Anyways, following is description:

> In this project, we prompt the user to chat using text + image. The text part is working fine, the problem is with the image part. Firstly, there is a file input which process images (line no: 160-173, script.js), then we prepare and send a request string to server (line no: 117-132, script.js). There we had a console log, which logs the length of request string (line no: 128, script.js). At this point, client-side task is over.
>
> Now, we have a Node server which captures the request string (line no: 27,28,29, in server.js). I’ve a problem here that, client and server logs different length of the same request string. I know client-side can’t be wrong as it is generating the string. My doubt is that the server is not completely capturing the string, as:

- it outputs a different length from the client
- it outputs different length every time, instead of a unique one

Why is this problem arising? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I understood why this is happening. It's bcoz node receives large request datas in **chunks**, and so I got **partial JSON data**, and Node threw error.

For testing purposes, one can check the following code on localhost:

- index.js

```
let http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs');

http.createServer((req, resp) => {
  if(req.method === 'GET' && req.url === '/') {
    fs.readFile('./index.html', (err, res) => {
      resp.writeHead('200', { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
      resp.end(res, 'utf8');
    });
  } else if(req.method === 'POST') req.on( 'data', chunk => console.log('Length', chunk.length) );
}).listen(8080);
```

- index.html

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="f(this);">
<script>
function f(el) {
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function() {
        console.log('Length', fr.result.length);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', '/', true);
        xhr.send(fr.result);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(el.files[0]);
};
</script>
```

---

### A handy solution

Write something like,

```
let chunk = '';
req.on('data', _chunk => chunk += _chunk).on('end', () => {
  // do something with chunk
});
```